# I want to follow a tutorial but my mirror modifier doesn't work like in video?

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror

So as you see on the video , the front side is moving together but the back side is not ! I want to follow a tutorial video but my mirror and the tutorial mirror is behave differently ! But why ? As I see on the tutorial both sides moving together ! [Here is the video how my mirror works!](https://youtu.be/KtXwOAf_Ykk)

Comment: in your video, the modifier works as it is supposed to work, but what tutorial are you following?

Comment: Soo here is the tutorial video ! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiIoWrOlIRw&t=58s  Look at 1:46 !

And then look mine ! 
https://youtu.be/ryaCry_p720

Its looks different !

Comment: he uses the box (B) to select both the front and back vertices, but sorry I'm not even sure that's what you're trying to do

Comment: Oops, sorry, @moonboots, crossed wires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video, (having used it before,) the tutor is still using <kbd>B</kbd> Box-Select, in the shot you're referring to. In wireframe mode, that will select every vertex, however deep, within the box.

In your video, you are selecting directly, with a right-click. This will only select the vertex closest to the viewing plane.

Comment: Ohh man ! Thank you you just saved me ! I was trying like 4 ours ! Thanks !